# Is there a live html preview plugin/script for Vim?

Tags: php, html, css, vim

I love using vim, however I was wondering if it is possible to preview html or web pages as you type? Or any other similar scripts that help use vim for web design.

So far I have heard of [Zen coding](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981).

Comment: Well that's still pretty troublesome though cause you have to :w to save then mouve the mouse to the browser and the click refresh....

Comment: Alt + TAB then F5 will be your friend after saving.

Comment: You could write a JS script that refreshes the page every `n` seconds.. ala [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/#synopsis) watch mode.

Comment: Good alternative, but refreshing the page every second creates a flash of the web browser. Quite distracting if you ask me...

Answer (score 1):

Zen Coding is very powerful but it has nothing to do with live preview.

You can't have live preview because Vim only writes on the disc when you explicitly ask with `:w` or a similar command. Whatever you do between two "writes" happens in memory (hence "buffers") so, you can reload the file in your browser as many times as you want you won't have authentic live preview: the file is still the same.

You are left with two possibilities: "reload on save" and "reload every x seconds".

1. I don't know of a reliable/easy/cross platform/cross browser way to achieve "reload on save". [LiveReload](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/livereload/) didn't work for me and its younger sister [LR2](http://livereload.com/) is Mac only. Try them if you want. I think I've seen a vim plugin that did that some times ago but I couldn't find the link ATM. One could use Firefox's API, maybe.
2. "reload every x seconds" can be achieved easily with a browser extension like Auto Refresh Plus for Chrome which I've been using for a while (it doesn't seem to exist anymore…) or any of the dozens of alternatives for Firefox or Opera or Safari.

Comment: You might be interested by [this script](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown).

Answer (score 1):

Quite some time ago, My atari had this thing (using [OLGA](ftp://ftp.pigwa.net/stuff/collections/atari_forever/www-magazines/MyAtari.net/07/olga.htm)) that would allow one program to tell another to refresh it's input files.

I don't think anything much exists to force a browser to monitor disk files like this, it only really suits static on-disk HTML/CSS work, tbh there isn't much of this these days.

That said, with chrome you can get the browser to refresh using [**ChromeReload**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo) for you without resorting to javascript or meta tags. You can get Firefox to do the same with **[ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I heard about [tincr](http://tin.cr/) last saturday at the dotjs conference in Paris. It's a Chrome extension that allows you to:

- edit your document in Vim or whatever and see the changes "live" on each `:w`
- play with css rules and stuff in Chrome's dev tools and have your changes propagated in your local files

That's quite cool but I couldn't make the versioning work.

Also, since it's an answer to a common question I'll post it verbatim in other places as well. I hope it's not considered as advertising: I have no relationship whatsoever with the people behind this extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the plugin (and the browser) I've just made for this purpose : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4908
And the browser (need to compile from sources) : https://gitorious.org/clcbrowser/clcbrowser
(I'll do a windows installer soon)

The combination of both allows you to live preview php (and other html related), html and css while you are typing. An option allows you to disable the "live" mode to refresh the page only when the buffer is saved. It handle local server files too. So editing a file in /srv/http/** (default path which is mine, but customizable) will launch the browser at `http://localhost/**` (also customisable).

For css, it launch all files listed in .css.preview, or all index.{php, html, htm} found in the same path if no preview file.